# How to open a new web page from a Javascript triggered by a Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to open a new web page with a specific URL from a Javascript triggered by a Google Form (Google Apps Script). Can someone help me with the proper syntax?

Comment: You should take a look at [this example](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/02/20/open-site-with-new-window-using-google-apps-script/), it goes over this very thing.

Comment: This might be what you want: https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293